# How to get all class initializers using reflection in Swift

Tags: swift, reflection, initialization, mirror

I'm trying to get all signature of initializer from the class in Swift. Initializer can mirror, I can find the signatures like below code.

```
enum MessageType {
    case say
    case shout
    case wisper
}

class Message {
    var text = ""
    var type : MessageType = .say
    init(text: String, type: MessageType) {
        self.type = type
        self.text = text
    }
    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
}

let firstInit = Message.init(text:)
let secondInit = Message.init(text:type:)

let firstMirror = Mirror(reflecting: firstInit)
let secondMirror = Mirror(reflecting: secondInit)

print(firstMirror.subjectType)
// (String) -> Message

print(secondMirror.subjectType)
// ((String, MessageType)) -> Message
```

However, this code requires to specify `init` which I want to look it up. What I expected is something like below:

```
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: Message)

let inits = mirror.initializers
// something like [Message.init(text:), Message.init(text:type:)] as [Any]

for method in inits {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: method)
    print(method.subjectType)
}
```

How can I get all `init` initializers from class using Mirror?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Mirror` struct in Swift offers some runtime introspection features, but for the default case, these focus on the instance being reflected upon rather than the type of that instance. From the [language reference for `Mirror`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mirror):

> #### Mirror
>
> Representation of the sub-structure and optional “display style” of any arbitrary subject instance.
>
> **Overview**
>
> Describes the parts—such as stored properties, collection elements, tuple elements, or the active enumeration case—that make up
>   a particular instance. May also supply a “display style” property that
>   suggests how this structure might be rendered.

You can implement a custom mirror for you `Message` type by conforming to the [`CustomReflectable`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/customreflectable) protocol. Implementing a custom mirror with the single purpose of listing available initializers, however, would still require manually supplying the initializer's information to the implementation of the custom mirror.

E.g.:

```
extension Message: CustomReflectable {
    var customMirror: Mirror {
        let children = DictionaryLiteral<String, Any>(dictionaryLiteral:
            ("init(text:)", type(of: Message.init(text:))),
            ("init(text:type:)", type(of: Message.init(text:type:))))

        return Mirror.init(Message.self, children: children,
                           displayStyle: .class)
    }
}

// using your custom mirror
let myMessage = Message(text: "foo")
for case (let label?, let value) in Mirror(reflecting: myMessage).children {
    print("\(label), \(value)")
} /* init(text:), (String) -> Message
     init(text:type:), ((String, MessageType)) -> Message */
```

This manual implementation requirement possibly defeats the very purpose of the exercise though. Note also that reflection must still be performed upon an instance rather than the type itself (so possibly it's easier to simply implement a dictionary describing the initializers directly as a `static` type property; but the manual form of this implementation defeats much of its value).

Comment: so is there a better way for doing it on the class level?